# Convert vectorwise queries into Synapse queries

Tags: sql, azure-synapse, vectorwise

Is there any third party tool which can convert Vectorwise query into Synapse queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such tool available.

Azure Synapse support T-SQL language to query and analyze the data. You can use standard ANSI-compliant dialect of SQL language used on SQL Server and Azure SQL Database for data analysis.

Since vectorwise query is similar to T-SQL, you can try if some of the statements supported by Synapse. Else, you need to write them in T-SQL and use.